# Generate ORM classes for Brick Ontology using OLGA code gen

Tags: code-generation, owl, ontology, rdfs

I am new to Ontologies and I am trying to generate POCO/POJO (C#/Java) classes from Brick ontology using OLGA CodeGen. OLGA works for the sample ontology provided on their Github page but for Brick it is throwing an 'Invalid Class Name' error.

I am expecting that if I supply a ttl/owl Brick file then the CodeGen should be able to generate the classes and also class properties (data and object properties) e.g.
Building -> BuildingPrimaryFunction, hasAddress, hasPart(floors) etc.

Steps that I've tried:

1. Download the latest brick.ttl file(v1.2.0) from  https://brickschema.org/schema/1.2.0/Brick.ttl
2. Installed OLGA (v0.0.6) from https://github.com/EcoStruxure/OLGA
3. To Generate the code from the file this is the command that I use.

> java -jar OLGA-Cli/target/OLGA-Cli-0.0.6-with-dependencies.jar --code java --library rdf4j --name BrickSchemaClasses --path Brick.ttl --out .

I see the following error

> 2021-06-28 20:20:08 ERROR OLGA:90 - semanticstore.ontology.library.generator.exceptions.InvalidClassNameException: PM2.5_Concentration Invalid class name, it doesn't follow the convention.
> PM2.5_Concentration Invalid class name, it doesn't follow the convention.
> **

I've even saved the file as .owl using protégé and still I get the same error.
Is there any step or any preprocessing of the file that I'm missing before I provide the file to OLGA,
OR are there any other similar codegen libraries that will help me generate POJO Java/C# classes from an ontology?

I would really appreciate any help or direction.

Thanks

Comment: you should ask the OLGA people directly. Probably here https://github.com/EcoStruxure/OLGA/issues

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to be too much action happening there. I was hoping someone from the community would have tried this before.